# Convert generic type to string and back

Tags: c#, generics, type-conversion

I want to build a simple generic `Range` that has a lower and a upper bound.

```
public abstract class Range<T> 
{
    Range(T lower, T upper){/* init _lowerValue and _upperValue (both of type T) */}

    // this method I would use inside TypeConverter...
    public static Range<T> Parse(string source){/* build a new instance from string, but how? */}

    public LowerString => ValueToString(_lowerValue);
    public UpperString => ValueToString(_upperValue);

    public abstract string ValueToString(T value); // must be overridden
    public abstract T StringToValue(string source); // must be overridden

    public string AsString => $"{LowerString},{UpperString}"; // gets the string-representation of the object
}
```

With an example implementation for `DateTime`

```
public class DateTimeRange : Range<DateTime>
{
    public override string ValueToString(DateTime value) => value.ToString("O");
    public override DateTime StringToValue(string source) => DateTime.Parse(source);
}
```

In my code I can now create a new DateTimeRange an pass it to my api-enpoint as query-parameter

> http:/.../api/EndPoint?range=2016-10-21T18:08:03.6190988Z,2016-11-21T18:08:03.6190988Z

But how can I convert this back on api-side? There I only have the string `2016-10-21T18:08:03.6190988Z,2016-11-21T18:08:03.6190988Z` and know the type in my contoller-action

> EndpointController.Get(DateTimeRange range){/* do something with the parsed range */}

but no idea how to convert this back to `Range<DateTime>`.

I've already looked into `TypeConverter` but don't find anything useful about generics there.

Is using type-converter here the correct way to go or are there any other best-practices on how this can be achieved?

Comment: Why not just create a constructor on `DatTimeRange` that takes a `string`?

Comment: How you want to use this classes? Post an example...

Comment: Then I would need to create one TypeCoverter for each new implementation of Range<T> or change the existing one, no?

Comment: You have two values as a Range and want to convert to a single value??.. How to choose if LowerString or UpperString ?

Comment: @IgorQuirino Yes, mainly that's what I want.

Comment: @IgorQuirino I want those class(es) to be passed to various endpoints for filtering in ranges of `DateTime`, `int`, `double?`, whatever kind of range given. But I don't know how to convert the string back into the complex type via TypeConverter to let the ModelBinder do all the magic on API side

Comment: Will the bounds always be comma-separated? Then simply split the string into two parts and parse both of them. But I would suggest you use something more robust than simple comma-separation, something that will work for all possible types of T.

Comment: @Omilis for this question, yes. The main question is not how to parse. It's more about how parsing can be done under the hood with e.g. `TypeConverter`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot implement an static method on **Range** class accessing your implemented method without passing the object.

This could be fit to your needs:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/l2nOSp

```
public abstract class Range<T> 
{
    internal T Lower { get; set; }
    internal T Upper { get; set; }

    internal Range(T lower, T upper)
    {
        Lower = lower;
        Upper = upper;
    }

    // this method I would use inside TypeConverter...
    internal Range(string source)
    {
        string[] parts = source.Split(',');

        if(parts.Length <= 1)
            throw new ArgumentException();

        if(!this.CanConvert(parts[0]) || !this.CanConvert(parts[1]))
            throw new ArgumentException();

        this.Lower = this.StringToValue(parts[0]);
        this.Upper = this.StringToValue(parts[1]);
    }

    public string LowerString { get { return ValueToString(Lower); } }
    public string UpperString { get { return ValueToString(Upper); } }

    public abstract string ValueToString(T value); // must be overridden
    public abstract T StringToValue(string source); // must be overridden
    internal abstract bool CanConvert(string source); // must be overridden

    public string AsString { get { return string.Format("{0},{1}", LowerString, UpperString); }}// gets the string-representation of the object
}
```

And then **DateTimeRange** Class:

```
public class DateTimeRange : Range<DateTime>
{

    public DateTimeRange(string source) : base(source)
    {

    }

    public DateTimeRange(DateTime lower, DateTime upper):base(lower, upper)
    {

    }

    public override string ValueToString(DateTime value) { return value.ToString("O"); }
    public override DateTime StringToValue(string source) { return DateTime.Parse(source); }
    internal override bool CanConvert(string source) { DateTime dt = new DateTime(); return DateTime.TryParse(source, out dt); }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
Range<DateTime> a = new DateTimeRange(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-20), DateTime.Now);
Console.WriteLine(a.AsString);

Range<DateTime> b = new DateTimeRange("2016-11-01T19:38:05.6409410+00:00,2016-11-21T19:38:05.6409410+00:00");
Console.WriteLine(b.AsString);
```

**Endpoint Method:**

```
public void Get(string range) //EndpointController.Get
{
    Range<DateTime> b = new DateTimeRange(range);
    //Do what you need with properties:
    //b.LowerString
    //b.UpperString
}
```

Happy to help you!

Comment: Thanks. Two things. Is the virtual member-call in constructor okay here?
Second one: Therefore again I do need a new TypeConverter for each new Range-implementation, no?. I was hoping/looking for something that could help with my generic struggle when converting back...

Comment: How you can know the target type of conversion?

Comment: If you dont know what to expect, how generic can be your system?

Comment: I thought that .NET is looking for a TypeConverter when the param in action is of type x. So, for Get(DateTimeRange range), the type of range is known by ModelBuilder/TypeConverter. https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api

Comment: you can pass a string in your parameter and then convert under the code. yes? no?

Comment: That's what I actually do. I thought of something easier than everytime calling the ctor with string. So I ended up with the article about TypeConverters. But then I have one TypeConverter per implementation. 
So your solution is perfectly fine. It's maybe me who expected too much magic

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128649/discussion-between-kingkerosin-and-igor-quirino).

Comment: See my other answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a single type (but without custom formatters):

https://dotnetfiddle.net/nXsI2S

```
public class Range<T>
{
    internal T Lower { get; set; }
    internal T Upper { get; set; }

    private Range()
    {
    }

    internal Range(T lower, T upper)
    {
        Lower = lower;
        Upper = upper;
    }

    internal Range(string source)
    {
        string[] parts = source.Split(',');

        if(parts.Length <= 1)
            throw new ArgumentException();

        var tc = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T));

        if(!Range<T>.CanConvert(source))
            throw new ArgumentException("string in invalid format", "source");

        this.Lower = ((T)tc.ConvertFrom(parts[0]));
        this.Upper = ((T)tc.ConvertFrom(parts[1]));
    }

    public static bool CanConvert(string source)
    {
        string[] parts = source.Split(',');

        if(parts.Length <= 1)
            throw new ArgumentException();

        var tc = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T));

        if(!tc.CanConvertFrom(typeof(string)))
           return false;

        return tc.IsValid(parts[0]) && tc.IsValid(parts[1]);
    }

    public static Range<T> Parse(string source)
    {
        Range<T> ret = new Range<T>();

        string[] parts = source.Split(',');

        if(parts.Length <= 1)
            throw new ArgumentException("string in invalid format", "source");

        if(!Range<T>.CanConvert(source))
            throw new ArgumentException("string in invalid format", "source");

        return new Range<T>(source);
    }

    public string LowerString { get { return Lower.ToString(); } }
    public string UpperString { get { return Upper.ToString(); } }

    public string AsString { get { return string.Format("{0},{1}", LowerString, UpperString); }}// gets the string-representation of the object
}
```

**Usage:**

```
string range = "2016-10-01T19:38:05.6409410+00:00,2016-11-21T19:38:05.6409410+00:00";

if(Range<int>.CanConvert(range))
    Console.WriteLine(Range<int>.Parse(range).AsString);

if(Range<DateTime>.CanConvert(range))
    Console.WriteLine(Range<DateTime>.Parse(range).AsString);
```

Comment: this looks more closer of what you need.